# Ruby on Rails: Assign an attribute to nil if validation fails

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My question is how to assign an attribute to `nil` if it's invalid?
Let's say I have a custom validator

```
validate :record_format


def record_format
  error_messages = CustomValidator.new.errors.full_messages

  errors.add(:base, error_messages)
end
```

`CustomValidator` is used in a few different places.
So instead of `errors.add(:base, error_messages)` I want to assign my attribute to `nil` on a failed validation only in one class. Is there a profound way to do so apart from just setting it directly as `attribute_name = nil`?

Thanks

Comment: If you already know that you do not really want to validate the attribute but instead want to assign `nil` to that attribute under certain conditions then I would suggest using a `before_validation` callback and not a custom validation.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks! The thing is this `custom logic` is a shared validator class `CustomValidator`. So in short `error_messages = CustomValidator.new.errors` And I need to set the attribute to nil for one class only and not in others.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your requirements. Would you mind elaborating on what you actually want to achieve? Might make sense to add more code to your question to make the use-case clear. Because of your comment, my answer would be that you can share `before_validation` or `before_save` callbacks too.

Comment: Just be as explicit as possible and set this attribute directly to nil where it is necessary leaving the validator to just validate... But the fact that you have different validation rules for different scenarios might be a sight that your app complexity overgrew the current design and you might need to think about refactoring. There are patterns in the wild (like DCI /for Data, Context, Interaction/) that address the issue you described in a natural way - by forcing case-specific business logic to be moved from fat data models to operations and/or contexts...